# Redirect from backend doesn't work, browser does a GET request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, redirect

I have an angular application that makes a request to the backend (Spring boot server) that isn't authorized. I receive the following response from the server.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
Vary: Origin
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Method
Vary: Access-Control-Request-Headers
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 ; includeSubDomains
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Location: https://localhost:4200/oauth2/login/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 25 Sep 2019 12:26:40 GMT
```

I want it to redirect me to the login page and the server return in the Location header the correct url for the login page but my browser tries to make a OPTIONS request to "https://localhost:4200/oauth2/login/" that gives 200 code, but not load the page. How can I redirect this to my web angular page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, your front-end logic is separate from server-side logic, this means your server cannot handle redirection on the client-side. With that said, one approach is to obtain the status code from the response and determine if redirection needs to happen. You can do this by injecting the Angular Router module into your authentication class where you can then use the navigate method to redirect the user to the location of choice.

Comment: I received from backend 302 reponse, I expected that the browser will redirect to location from the response